# Узнать количество элементов, возвращаемых функцией через указатель

Tags: c++, c, массивы, функции, указатели

Допустим, у нас есть структура

```
struct get_query 
{
    char name[200];
    char value[200];
};
```

и функция, возвращаемый тип которой такой же:

```
struct get_query *get_array(char *str);
```

Она возвращает несколько элементов `get_query`, вызываю так:

```
struct get_query *data = get_array(str);
```

Вопрос такой: можно ли как то вызвать так

```
struct get_query data[] = get_array(str);
```

чтобы можно было узнать количество элементов в `data`. Если возможно, опишите пожалуйста, как.

Comment: есть два способа - либо Вы явно возвращаете размер (хоть через глобальную переменную), либо в конец массива добавьте ещё один элемент, который "пустой". Но это все не с++:)

Comment: Если Вам нужен c++, то я бы вообще рекомендовал использовать более высокоуровневые конструкции, типа `std::string` и `std::vector`. Наличие сразу двух меток: [tag:c] и [tag:с++] только лишь раздувает объём ответа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сделать

```
struct get_query *get_array(char *str, int * count);
```

и передать в `count` количество элементов. Если C++ - можно использовать ссылку

```
struct get_query *get_array(char *str, int & count);
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Массивы не имеют оператора присваивания. И кроме того функции не могут возвращать массивы. В C++ функции могут возвращать ссылки на массив, но тем не менее вы не сможете один массив присвоить другому массиву.

В C++ вы могли бы возвращать объект типа `std::pair<get_query *, size_t>`, то есть возвращать пару из указателя на первый элемент массива и число элементов в массиве.

В C вы могли бы сами определить такую структуру. Например,

```
struct Pair
{
    struct get_query *data;
    size_t n;
};
```

и возвращать эту структуру из функции. Например

```
 struct Pair get_array(char *str);
```

Или в C вы можете дополнить массив еще одним элементом, который будет содержать значение `NULL`. Используя это граничное значение, вы можете подсчитать число элементов в выделенном массиве.

Альтернативный подход в C++ и в C - это изменить объявление функции. Например, вы могли бы передавать в функцию исходный указатель по ссылке, а из функции возвращать число элементов в выделенном массиве. Например,

```
 size_t get_array(get_query **data, char *str);
```

В C++ вы могли бы параметр объявить как ссылку. Наример

```
 size_t get_array(get_query * &data, char *str);
```